# regex for date in java

Tags: java, regex, date

can someone help me what would be the regular expression in java for the string "Feb. 26, 2009  8:08 AM PST"????

Answer (score 4):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead of using regexp. Read [the tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

UPD: regexp will look like: `"(Jan|Feb|Mar).*PST"` where list of months should contain all 12 (instead of 3 as in my example). But it's very very unreliable.

Comment: @Freiheit: everytime I see a question about dates in java I'm waiting for the answer/comment like "and don't forget that java dates are broken, use Joda Time instead". And as I understand I'm not alone in this habit.

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with parse would probably be simpler in Java.  See example below.  The Javadoc shows what each of the letters in the pattern means.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM. dd, YYYY h:mm a Z");
Date date = null;
try {
   date = formatter.parse(datestring);
} catch(ParseException pe) {
   throw new IllegalArguementException(datestring + " is not properly formatted!", pe);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ya but the problem is that the date which i am trying to extract is nested inside some text. So i was looking for a regex and using it with split method of string in java to extract the dates from the particular string.

Comment: Is it an arbitrary date?  An arbitrary timezone?  The more you can guarantee about the date, the simpler the regex will be.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a simple date with just the above format. I just need to match dates out from a huge text document, and extract them out.

str.split("regex for the above date");

Comment: @sahmed - it will be a little bit (in reputation) before you can post comments everywhere, but you should be able to update your own question and also comment on it - check it out and see!

Answer (score 0):

i think my approach is wrong. If i use str.split("regex for date"); to extract all the dates from the text. Its not gonna do that but it will retain the other text and split the document when the date occurs.

How do i do what i intend to do , that is from a text extract all the dates perferably in an array which corresopnds to the above format of date??

Comment: Look at `Pattern` and `Matcher` in the Java API.  Those will do what you want.  Also, consider using comments and editing your original post.  This would be an ideal edit.